# How to fix service error Oracle jws webserver

Tags: linux, redhat, java-web-start, httpd.conf

After RHEL6-7 migration setting up oracle jws web servers says "error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory "

/apps/oracle/jws-webserver-3.0.3/jws_proxy/httpd/sbin/httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you add more information? It's hard to understand what's your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like your migration messed up a couple of things.

Check if you actually have or not the library.

```
find / -name libpcre.so.1
```

If you do, then check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, if not, then add the path to it so the binary can get it.

Another option is, pcre is not even installed, then process to get it and install it.